# Display seller names according to their selling Prices

Tags: price, product-view, multi-vendor

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site.

In our site lot of sellers have same Products, so in Product view page we display all sellers.

assume a Product is uploaded by seller "kidsdial4" , than same product is assigned by another seller "kidsdial6".

so in product view page, we are displaying both seller names like [this](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

on top you can see  seller kidsdial4 with Price Rs .20:

[image]

on bottom you can see seller kidsdial 6 with Price Rs .10:

[image]

here `seller kidsdial4 have Price Rs 20 for that product.

& kidsdial6 seller have have Price Rs.10 for that product.

so i want to **display seller on top who is selling for lowest price**

here, kidsdial 6 should display on top , kidsdial 4 should display on bottom.

we are trying below script in view.phtml , now in both above & below , `Kidsdial6 seller name and his price displaying`.

but i want to `display Kidsdial4 seller name & his price` in below.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function getPriceFromString(str){
            return str.replace( /^\D+/g, '')
    }

    productPriceFormated = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form span.price').text();
    productPrice = getPriceFromString(productPriceFormated);
    lowestPrice = productPrice;
    productId = 0;
    soldBy = ''


    jQuery('#seller-list-new form').each(function(index){
        price = getPriceFromString(jQuery(this).find('span span.price').text());

        if(price < lowestPrice){
            lowestPrice = price;
            productId = jQuery(this).find('.mpassignproduct_id').val()
            soldBy =  jQuery(this).find('div.wk_seller_profile').html()
        }

    });

    if(productId > 0){
        jQuery('#product_addtocart_form span.price').text(productPriceFormated.replace(productPrice, lowestPrice));
        jQuery('input:hidden[name=product]').remove();
        jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').prepend('<input type="hidden" value="' + productId + '" name="mpassignproduct_id" class="mpassignproduct_id">');
        jQuery('#product_addtocart_form .soled-by-dealer span').html(soldBy)
    }
});
```

complete code of `app/design/frontend/default/default/template/mpassignproduct/sellerlist.phtml` => http://pasted.co/13849662

**wk_block.phtml**

```
<?php
    $helper=Mage::helper('marketplace');
    $_product=Mage::registry('current_product');
    $productowner=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->isCustomerProduct($_product['entity_id']);
    if($productowner['userid']!=""){
        $captchenable = $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/captcha');
        $rowsocial=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
?>

<div class="block wk-block block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><span>
    <?php   if($rowsocial['shoptitle']!='')
            echo $rowsocial['shoptitle'];
        else
            echo  $rowsocial['profileurl']; ?>
    </span></strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="wk_blockdetail">   
            <ul class="partnerlinks">
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('marketplace/seller/collection').$rowsocial['profileurl'] ?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Visit Complete Collection') ?>" id="siteconnect"><?php echo $helper->__('View Collection') ?></a>
                </li>
                <li class="profile-view">
                    <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl()."marketplace/seller/profile/".$rowsocial['profileurl'] ?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Visit Profile') ?>" id="profileconnect"><?php echo $helper->__('View Profile') ?></a>
                    <div class="wk-block-hover-div">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        <?php echo $rowsocial['compdesi']; ?>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml();?>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

full code of wk_block.phtml : http://pasted.co/0a221176

**Sellerlist.php**

```
app/code/local/Exam/Mpassignproduct/Block/Sellerlist.php

<?php

class Exam_Mpassignproduct_Block_Sellerlist extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout() {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function sellerNewProductList() {
        $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition', array('eq'=>'new'));
        $collection->setOrder("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function sellerUsedProductList() {
        $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition',array('eq'=>'used'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'));
        $collection->setOrder("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

i will give extra 100 bounty points if i get answer....

Comment: this is `Rs. 20.00` product price?

Comment: 20 is price of kidsdial4 and 10 is price of kidsdial 6.

Comment: but this product current price? i am asking that

Comment: we are displaying both prices in view page , so that buyer can buy any product [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

Comment: @BabyinMagento Template file is not enough. I need to take a look into its Block file.

Comment: @ToanNguyen please check updated question & let me know if you want to check other code.

Comment: @BabyinMagento Unfortunately, it is not enough. You are providing `sellerlist.phtml` and the other related to the block `kidsdial6` at the bottom. But what you want is change the logic of code, which related to part you replaced before in `Sold by` block. Please give me the file which call `sellerlist.phtml` and its Block.

Comment: @ToanNguyen we are calling sellerlist.phtml in view.phtml file  & please check other 2 blocks of code here . view.phtml = > mpassignproduct.php => http://pasted.co/87136bc3  , mpassignproductlist.php = http://pasted.co/143e776d

Comment: this is used for `sellerUsedProductList` current seller id? and this `sellerNewProductList` lsiting the other prices?

Comment: @QaisarSatti http://prnt.sc/au29tr when creating assign products, we use 2 types. - 1) new  2) used.

`sellerNewProductList` = if we select New when creating product

`sellerUsedProductList` = if we select used  when creating product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your price is not sorting try `$collection->getSelect()->setOrder()`

```
public function sellerNewProductList() {
    $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition', array('eq'=>'new'));
        $collection->getSelect()->order("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }


public function sellerUsedProductList() {
    $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition',array('eq'=>'used'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'));
    $collection->getSelect()->order("price",ASC);
    return $collection;
}
```

for checking it is sorting try to run query  `echo $collection->getSelect();`

Comment: i am checking and let you know soon. i changed one function to `sellerUsedProductList()`

Comment: sorry, it did't worked for me.

Comment: you code is not complete bro add the `view.phtml` code too

Comment: please check view.phtml : http://pastebin.com/QEs1y6EJ

Comment: Not Found error

Comment: please check [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html) , only base seller is displaying, assign seller is not displaying.

Comment: if your current product of base seller then the base seller it's price will be shown.

Comment: base seller product have more price than assigned seller, so i want to display assign seller on top and base seller on bottom.
but here only base seller is displayuing.

Comment: but the this is simple it not count when you showing the base seller then you will show the base seller name and price because when you add to cart it will add base seller product

Comment: please visit [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-metal-mechanix-13.html) we are displaying 2 ADD TO CART button

Comment: if buyer clicks on add-to-cart present above, it will add base seller product & price, in same way 
if buyer  click on add-to-cart button below, than assign seller product price will add

Comment: when you switch prices then it will be confusing you have put `as  low as` just highlight the low price

Comment: so we want to switch both seller name and price. client want something like this only.

Comment: they are not concern which price is adding in cart?

Comment: are you telling about buyer, but buyer will check both seller prices and they will add least price right ?
so only we want to display least seller price on top.

Comment: but when you switch prices the product id will be same. you have to change base seller only with lowest price.

Comment: product id is same. if seller A seller for Rs 100 - top, seller B sell for Rs 50 - bottom , than we can not
display seller A - 50 price on top.

Comment: we have to switch both seller name and price. after this feature we need to switch other things like shipping charges, delivery time, cash on delivery available or not.

Comment: please let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: i have to see the code of ext then i will say something