# Display In-Stock Seller/Vendor on top of product view page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view, out-of-stock, multi-vendor

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site.

we are displaying multiple sellers on product view page.

initially one  Product is uploaded by seller "kidsdial4" , than same product is assigned by another seller "kidsdial6".

than in product view page, we are displaying both seller names like [this](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

on top you can see  seller kidsdial4:

[image]

on bottom you can see seller kidsdial 6:

[image]

here `seller kidsdial4 have "zero" stock` [out-of-stock ] for that product.

& kidsdial6 seller have quantity for that product.

so i want to display kidsdial 6 seller on top , kidsdial 4 should display on bottom.

**sellerlist.phtml**

```
<?php $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId(); ?>
<?php if(count($this->sellerNewProductList())!=0 || count($this->sellerUsedProductList())!=0): ?>
    <div class="wk_mp_design" id="seller-list" style="clear:both">
        <div class="block block-account">
            <div class="head block-title">
                <strong>
                    <span class="wk_new_tab list_active_tab" for="seller-list-new"><?php echo $this->__('Sold By')." ".count($this->sellerNewProductList())."" ." Sellers "; ?></span>
                    <!-- <span class="wk_tab_seperator"></span>
                    <span class="wk_used_tab" for="seller-list-used"><?php echo $this->__('Used')." (".count($this->sellerUsedProductList()).")";?></span> -->
                </strong>
            </div>
            <div class="seller-list" id="seller-list-new">
                <?php if(count($this->sellerNewProductList())==0): ?>
                    <div class="fieldset wk_mp_fieldset">
                        <div class="wk_emptymsg">
                            <?php echo $this->__('No New Product Available') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="title">
                        <span class="lable profile"><?php echo $this->__('Sellers');?></span>
                        <span class="lable comment"><?php echo $this->__('Delivered By');?></span>
                        <span class="lable price"><?php echo $this->__('Price');?></span>
                        <span class="lable addto"><?php echo $this->__('');?></span>
                    </div>
                    <?php foreach($this->sellerNewProductList() as $seller): ?>
                        <?php
                            $userlist=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                            $userlist->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$seller->getSellerId()));
                            foreach($userlist as $user){
                                $profileurl=$user->getProfileurl();
                                $logo=$user->getLogopic();
                            }
                        ?>
```

complete code of sellerlist.phtml` => http://pasted.co/13849662

**wk_block.phtml**

```
<?php
    $helper=Mage::helper('marketplace');
    $_product=Mage::registry('current_product');
    $productowner=Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->isCustomerProduct($_product['entity_id']);
    if($productowner['userid']!=""){
        $captchenable = $percent = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/captcha');
        $rowsocial=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getPartnerProfileById($productowner['userid']);
?>

<div class="block wk-block block-viewed">
    <div class="block-title"><strong><span>
    <?php   if($rowsocial['shoptitle']!='')
            echo $rowsocial['shoptitle'];
        else
            echo  $rowsocial['profileurl']; ?>
    </span></strong></div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="wk_blockdetail">   
            <ul class="partnerlinks">
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl('marketplace/seller/collection').$rowsocial['profileurl'] ?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Visit Complete Collection') ?>" id="siteconnect"><?php echo $helper->__('View Collection') ?></a>
                </li>
                <li class="profile-view">
                    <a href="<?php echo  Mage::getUrl()."marketplace/seller/profile/".$rowsocial['profileurl'] ?>" title="<?php echo $helper->__('Visit Profile') ?>" id="profileconnect"><?php echo $helper->__('View Profile') ?></a>
                    <div class="wk-block-hover-div">
                        <div class="arrow"></div>
                        <?php echo $rowsocial['compdesi']; ?>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml();?>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

full code of wk_block.phtml : http://pasted.co/0a221176

**Sellerlist.php**

```
app/code/local/Exam/Mpassignproduct/Block/Sellerlist.php

<?php

class Exam_Mpassignproduct_Block_Sellerlist extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    public function _prepareLayout() {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function sellerNewProductList() {
        $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition', array('eq'=>'new'));
        $collection->setOrder("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function sellerUsedProductList() {
        $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition',array('eq'=>'used'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'));
        $collection->setOrder("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

i will give extra 100 bounty points if i get answer....

Comment: Can you provide us with the code of [this block](https://gyazo.com/e60ff2024e055713e1eb4d4cd40153c3)? (with the template code and block code both)

Comment: we wrote those code in view.phtml = > http://pastebin.com/ahNwEYZN

i think these are block codes : mpassignproductlist.php = > http://pasted.co/d70be2cc ,  mpassignproduct.php : http://pastebin.com/036dbHD4 .

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau i updated the question, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i already [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107596/display-seller-names-according-to-their-selling-prices) there so the same question

```
public function sellerNewProductList() {
    $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $collection=Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition', array('eq'=>'new'));
        $collection->getSelect()->order("price",ASC);
        return $collection;
    }


public function sellerUsedProductList() {
    $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition',array('eq'=>'used'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'));
    $collection->getSelect()->order("price",ASC);
    return $collection;
}
```

for checking it is sorting try to run query  `echo $collection->getSelect();`

Answer (score 2):

You can order the position of seller in your collection by modifying your both the seller collection like below.

As you have already filtered the Seller list by quantity having more than 0 value.

By ordering Price and Qty both you will get seller having less price at first place and if both the seller having same price then it will consider seller having more number of qty for that particular product as first place.

You can apply these to both your collection.

```
public function sellerUsedProductList() {
    $productid=Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('mpassignproduct/mpassignproduct')->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',array('eq'=>$productid))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('qty',array('gt'=>0))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('product_condition',array('eq'=>'used'))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('flag',array('eq'=>'1'));
 //    $collection->setOrder("price",ASC); your order by commented
          $collection->getSelect()->order("price ASC")->order("qty DESC");
    return $collection;
}
```

Let me know if you still have any problem.

Comment: i tried your code for `sellerUsedProductList() function`  , now in [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html) its displaying this result :  `SOLD BY 1 SELLERS` our products are new products, so i tried same way for `function sellerNewProductList()` , but i got this error : `Fatal error: Call to a member function order() on a non-object` in :  `$collection->getSelect->order("price ASC, qty DESC");`

Comment: Oops !! There is a type  You can try 

`$collection->getSelect()->order("price ASC , qty Desc");`

Comment: pleease check [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

Comment: `price` is a field name from your seller table. Replace `price` and `qty` from the seller table field name for eg if you are using `seller_price` field name in your Seller Product table. then replace `price` with `seller_price` same for `qty`

Comment: when i use only price or qty  as like `$collection->getSelect()->order("price ASC");` or  `$collection->getSelect()->order("qty Desc");`  , i dont get this error , but when i use both than only error.  &   i checked in related table , it showing like this :  http://prnt.sc/asglzm or did i checked in wrong table ?

Comment: this is error i am getting : http://prnt.sc/asgwgm

Comment: I understand the concern its syntext error. Please try below

`$collection->getSelect()->order("price ASC")->order("qty Desc");`

I misinterpret the method argument.

Comment: i tried your code, now there is no error, but still out of stock quantity seller is displaying above and in stock quantity seller is displaying below.

Comment: give me screenshot of it. or `echo $collection->getSelect()` in your method. i would like to check it in browser print this in your browser.

Comment: pls check here : http://prnt.sc/ashk9j , also [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

Comment: here on top , ADD-TO-CART button is not displaying because "kidsdial 4 have 0 quantity, if top seller have quantity, than it will display "Add to cart" as [here](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/zephyr-metal-mechanix-13.html)

Comment: As per the query everything ok... you might be doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: you may be right, how to find in which method i need to put this code :`echo $collection->getSelect()` can you guide me for folder and file.

Comment: This will print sql query you can place this in both the collection method so that you can exactly come to know. where is the error

Comment: i added that code before `return $collection` now please check [link](http://vikas.collagekingapp.com/assign.html)

Comment: execute this query in a phpmyadmin and let me know the result

Comment: please check here : http://prnt.sc/ashyvy

Comment: As you can see it returns only one row. means database query is working correct. you might have error somewhere else. Please debug it thoroughly. you might get the weaken point.

Comment: okay,i  will try....

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't do the code but the idea is very simple.
Before all, load all the sellers that have this product, create an array with the "name"=>"stock" , order the array with the hight value of the "stock" at first, and then loop around the array, loading the seller by the name, and using his stock to show it.

Comment: Thanks for nice idea, i will try & let you know how it goes, if possible please provide me the code, so that its going to be very helpfull for me.